# How can I reference {rand-guid} value from declarative binding in Azure function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

I have a C# script Azure function and am binding a blob as an output in function.json:

```
"bindings": [
    ...
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "eventOutputBlob",
      "path": "event-receiver-queue-container/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "DomBlobStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference the {rand-guid} parameter inside of my run.csx code so I can store it in a queue for later processing. Is this possible?

This doesn't work but is along the lines of what I was hoping to get in run.csx:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    string rand-guid,
    Stream eventOutputBlob, 
    TraceWriter log) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the way to do this was to change the method signature to bind to `CloudBlockBlob` instead of `Stream`:

```
public static async Task Run(
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        string rand-guid,
        Stream eventOutputBlob, CloudBlockBlob queueOutputBlob,
        TraceWriter log) {
    ...
    }
```

And to modify function.json to contain `inout` per this [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/952):

```
"bindings": [
    ...
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "eventOutputBlob",
      "path": "event-receiver-queue-container/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "DomBlobStorage",
      "direction": "out" "direction": "inout"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Now I can call `queueOutputBlob.Name` to get the name of the blob, which is equal to `{rand-guid}` in this case.